# What is a Cill for an external French door?

Tags: doors, glazing

I’ve been trying to purchase a door for my kitchen, but terms keep popping up that I don’t understand.

What is a Cill please? (This option popped up under door accessories)

[image]

Comment: What are the other options? What Country or language is the site in? I suspect it's an alternate spelling of "sill", meaning "threshold".

Comment: Search says it is a different spelling for sill, the piece at the bottom of the door.  Does not make sense if listed with the door handle parts, unless they mean the plate the handle goes though.

Comment: Lock cylinder would also not be abbreviated that way (at least in English), and the measurement says that isn't what is being referred to, built it would make more sense in the context of door handle. Simplest recommendation: Ask the seller.

Comment: It would make sense to put the handle, sill, locks, etc. together to get an identical finish/look, so the sill being listed as a "door accessory" makes sense to me when buying a door.

Answer (score 1):

Cill is sill.

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_sill):

> A windowsill (also written window sill or window-sill, and less
> frequently in British English, cill) is the horizontal structure or
> surface at the bottom of a window.

Or more generally, per [a window and door manufacturer in the UK](https://www.revealdoorsandwindows.co.uk/technical/whats-the-difference-between-a-cill-and-a-sill-a-sub-cill-and-an-cill-extension/).

> The oracle for the English language, the Oxford English Dictionary,
> lists cill as a variant spelling of sill.  The book, A Dictionary of
> Architecture and Landscape Architecture uses cill exclusively as is
> common within our industry which is the spelling we’ll use throughout
> the article and our website.  So, both spellings are correct although
> the most common usage is sill and not cill.

Comment: Wow. I've gotta say that if you have to head to the OED to justify your archaic spelling (especially in a trade), then you're really stretching to justify intentionally misspelling a word and boarders on pompous. Not in any way, shape or form an attack on this answer, but questioning the usages in the sources quoted. +1